# iOS App Building Server

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, provisioning-profile

I'd like to set up an OSX server that could build iOS apps on behalf of multiple developers. (The developers would provide data used to modify a template app project in defined ways to produce the project that is built.)

Each developer would provide:

1. A code signing certificate
2. A provisioning profile
3. other app specific data

The server would:

1. Do XXXXX with the certificate
2. Do YYYYY with the profile
3. Copy a template Xcode project and modify it by doing ZZZZZ to point to 1) and 2)
4. Build the project (I assume using xcodebuild) to produce the app package

Is there a way to set up an Xcode project to point to the provisioning file and the certificate file themselves rather than going through keychain and whatever Xcode does with provisioning profiles? (There is a related Q&A mentioning putting the provisioning file in a certain folder that Xcode uses, but that no longer appears to be the case in the latest Xcode.)

Comment: Not to be overly critical, but what can your service provide that me pressing "Archive" in Xcode couldn't do?

Comment: The requested server functionality is part of a larger system, whose purpose is not discussed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Teamcity by Jetbrains. It's a free, multi-featured continuous integration server and it can build and even test Xcode projects by using schemes. Here are some of the features:

- Automate code analyzing, compiling, and testing processes, providing instant feedback on build progress, problems and test failures, all in simple, intuitive web-interface;
- Run multiple builds and tests under different configurations and platforms simultaneously;
- Perform Pre-tested commits, helping the rest of a team sustain an uninterrupted workflow;
- Have build history insight with customizable statistics on build duration, success rate, code quality and custom metrics;

Link: http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/